# Prevent windows 7 or 8 from opening windows on top

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, window

When I launch a program on windows it usually opens on top. It does not care if you are currently working on the other screen. It will take off the focus on the window you are working on and give focus to the new program that just launched.

Apple computers do not have this problem. If you launch a program it will load in the background and it will be minimized. For example I often compile my code in visual studio and that usually takes about 30 seconds. I tend to work on other stuff meanwhile its compiling. If I am typing an email for example then all of a sudden I will not be able to type any more and the program will launch on top. It will be nice if the newly launch program opened minimized flashing in the taskbar.

Comment: This behavior is 100% handled by the application through the use of the Win32 library.  There isn't a setting you can enable/disable that would change the individual behavior of a specific application.

Comment: Also: [How do i keep a newly started program from taking focus?](http://superuser.com/questions/145266/how-do-i-keep-a-newly-started-program-from-taking-focus)